# C++ pointer not storing value

Tags: c++

```
word  word::Addstr(char * &arr)
{
    char * baka = nullptr;
    if (sent != nullptr)
    {
        baka = new char[size + strlen(arr) + 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            baka[i] = sent[i];
        }
        baka[size] = ' ';
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = size +2; i < size + strlen(arr) + 3; i++)
        {
            baka[i] = arr[a];
            a++;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        baka = new char[strlen(arr) + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(arr) + 1; i++)
        {
            baka[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    word ustad(baka);
    return ustad;
}
```

Here in the second loop char *baka is not storing arr[]'s value. I have sent the char pointer by reference yet still it's not working.

```
for (int i = size +2; i < size + strlen(arr) + 3; i++)
        {
            baka[i] = arr[a];
            a++;
        }
```

The constructors and all other things are accurate. Baka stores value in the first loop but in the second one it doesn't. Even here:

```
baka[size] = ' ';
```

Can someone pleases help with this!

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Where do you set the value of `size`?

Comment: As from the reference parameter declaration I'd expect you allocate memory for `arr` in your function, but I can't spot you're doing so anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baka[size + 1]` is uninitialised and probably `0`. Presumably you are then printing the resulting string and the print stops at the null terminator so you don't see the second part of the string.

If you were using `std::string` it would be much easier, your code would simply be:

```
std::string baka = sent + " " + arr;
```